# Converting string to Percent with 2 decimal points

Tags: c#

I have one requirement regarding format for percent.I am getting value from database like 24.7% . I need to convert it to 2 decimal places like 24.70% . I have tried some format methods but not getting succeed. Can someone help out on this.

Comment: Show what have you tried..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial issue easily resolved through Google, and shows no own attempts at solving the problem. This is SO, not Rent-A-Coder.

Comment: `I have tried some format methods`. Please show those codes.

Comment: Google "string.format padding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this would help:

```
string value = "24.7%".Trim();
Value = value.Replace("%", "");
decimal Value = decimal.Parse(value);
string decimalValue = Value.ToString("0.00");
string actualValue=decimalValue +"%";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code.

```
string sValue = "24.7%".Trim();  //Assign input string here
sValue = sValue.Replace("%", "");
decimal dValue = decimal.Parse(sValue);
string displayValue = dValue.ToString("0.00") + "%";  //displayValue will contain value 24.7%
```

OR

```
string sValue = "24.7%".Trim();  //Assign input string here
sValue = sValue.Replace("%", "");
decimal dValue = decimal.Parse(sValue);
string displayValue = String.Format("{0:0.00}", dValue) + "%";  //displayValue will contain value 24.7%
```

Thanks,
Amit Prajapti